# Bootstrap popover hide not working inside input-group in Firefox Browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

'Update: Just noticed the issue is only in Firefox Browser :/

My code below works fine when the input field is not inside an input-group class, but
when it is, - as it is needed for input-group-addon -, the popover will show ok on hover, but on click, it will hide then show up a moment later, without moving the mouse (no hover event).

Any ideas for a cause/solution? Thanks

```
<div class='form-group'>
                <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
                
                <input type="tel" id="cust_mobile" name="cust_mobile" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" data-content="popover content" required />
                </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var is_touch_device = ("ontouchstart" in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch;
      
    $('#cust_mobile').popover({
    trigger: is_touch_device ? "click" : "hover",
    placement: is_touch_device ? "top" : "bottom"
    });
         
    if (!is_touch_device) { 
        $('#cust_mobile').click(function(){      
        $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');   
        });
    }; 
      });
```

Comment: You mean it doesn't work when you add `input-group-addon` class to `#cust_mobile`? I tried your code and it works from me but take care `$('#cust_mobile).popover` should be `$('#cust_mobile').popover`.

Comment: Hi, yes, as per the update the issue is only present in Firefox, if I add the input-group class, popover won't hide. works fine in other browsers...